# Location does not show up on Map in the Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

when user clicks on instagram icon in my app, it takes him to the business instagram, but map does not have annotation.

I wonder what I am missing?

[image]

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>


NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=438681044"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Comment: did you add some line of code in appdegates.m file /

Comment: -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
        annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [self.instagram handleOpenURL:url];
}

Comment: ensure once your id is correct , check this http://blog.csdn.net/icetime17/article/details/48261403

Comment: `locationid` is correct because it brings the corresponding business photos, but map does not display.

Comment: try with static id once

Comment: Could you please illustrate ?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me and location id is correct. 
Maybe you could check if you disabled some permissions in instagram app or you have a problem with internet connection. Better to start with clean state , reinstall instagram , and try again.
Anyway it's not related to instagram map.

Openurl is deprecated in iOS 10 :

```
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://location?id=438681044"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```